# .NET COM Object Performance In Lotus Notes 8.5

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, lotus-notes, x509certificate

First let me tell you I'm new to the .NET world, but have been Software Emgineer for 16 years, so I'm not new to coding. I ran across something that has me baffled, and maybe a more seasoned .NET developer might know what is causing a perfomance issue of my COM object. I have spent days browsing through forums with no luck, I decide to seek help by putting this post together.  I have developed my .NET code in VS 2010 using C#.  I know, the IDE is little aged. The code is pretty simple. The main method takes the Certificates encoded string, converts it to a byte format, and passes that to the X509Certificate object. I then use the objects method to get the expiration date. I also added a memory clean-up class hoping it would solve my problem. It did not.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //Need for API

namespace CertificationInfo
{
    //Certification Class
    public class CertificateInformation
    {
        //[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        //public static extern bool SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr proc, int min, int max); 


        //Class Attributes
        //private X509Certificate CertificateObject;
        public string CertificateData; 
        public string ExpirationDate;
        private MemoryManagement MemMngr;

        //Constructor
        public CertificateInformation()
        {
            //Reset Expiration Date
            this.ExpirationDate = "";
            MemMngr = new MemoryManagement();
        }

        //Method
        public string GetCertExpirationDate(string rawdata)
        {
            try
            {
                //Clean Up Memory
                this.MemMngr.ReleaseMemory();

                //Reset Expiration Date Property
                this.ExpirationDate = "";

                //Check for data
                if (rawdata == "" && this.CertificateData == "")
                {
                    //Nothing is passed & property is blank
                    this.ExpirationDate = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    //Check for Raw Data value
                    if (rawdata != "")
                    {
                        this.CertificateData = rawdata;
                    }

                    //Convert Property Array
                    //Might be best to use unicode Under Encoding namespace
                    //System.Text.UnicodeEncoding Encoding0=new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding();
                    //Byte[] bytedata0=Encoding0.GetBytes(rawdata);

                    //Convert Property to byte array
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding Encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                    Byte[] bytedata = Encoding.GetBytes(this.CertificateData);


                    //Create Encoding Object
                    X509Certificate CertificateObject = new X509Certificate(bytedata);
                    //this.CertificateObject = new X509Certificate(bytedata);

                    //Might have to check to see iff cert object is null though catch should pick it up 

                    //Get Expiration date
                    this.ExpirationDate = CertificateObject.GetExpirationDateString();

                    //Reset Object & Certificate Data Property
                    CertificateObject = null;
                    Encoding = null;
                    this.CertificateData = "";

                    //Clean Up Memory
                    this.MemMngr.ReleaseMemory();
                }
            }
            //Error Trapping in case of error still returns something
            catch
            {
                this.ExpirationDate = "";
            }

            return this.ExpirationDate;
        }

    }

    //API Class to Clean up Memory threads
    public class MemoryManagement
    {
        //Memory Management API
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr proc, int min, int max);

        //Method
        public void ReleaseMemory()
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
            {
                SetProcessWorkingSetSize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I moved it into the GAC, and registered it as a DLL on my local machine.  I then created a Lotus Script agent, that loops through all my documents(records). In the iteration it pulls a field into a string, passes it to method, and returns the expiration date as a string

%REM
    Agent TestDLL
    Created Jan 13, 2014 by Keith Wiwel/TPS/PGH/PNC
    Description: Comments for Agent
%END REM
Option Public
Option Declare

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim Session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim view As NotesView
    Dim document As NotesDocument
    Dim COMObj As Variant


    'Counts
    Dim TotalCount As Long
    Dim MissingDataCount As Long
    Dim COMErrorCount As Long
    Dim COMSuccessCount As Long


    Print "ETH - GetExpirationDLL: Initializing Notes Objects"
    Set db=Session.Currentdatabase
    Set view=db.Getview("Active Certificates - By Web Site")
    Print "ETH - GetExpirationDLL: Initializing COM Object"
    Set COMObj=CreateObject("CertificationInfo.CertificateInformation")


    TotalCount=0
    MissingDataCount=0
    COMErrorCount=0
    COMSuccessCount=0

    Print "ETH - GetExpirationDLL: Start Processing"
    Set document=view.Getfirstdocument()

    Do Until document Is Nothing
        TotalCount=TotalCount+1
        Print "Processing..."+CStr(TotalCount)

        'Expiration Variables
        Dim expirationdate As String
        Dim rawdata As String
        Dim legacyexpirationdate As String

        'Get data & Legacy Values
        'rawdata
        rawdata=CStr(Trim(document.Getitemvalue("CRT_File")(0)))
        legacyexpirationdate=CStr(document.expirationdate(0))

        If rawdata="" Then
            'Capture Certificates with No CSR Data
            document.ExpirationDate=""
            If LegacyExpirationDate="" Then
                document.LegacyExpirationDate=legacyexpirationdate  
            End If
            document.COMError="Missing CSR"
            Call document.Save(True,False)
            MissingDataCount=MissingDataCount+1
        Else
            'Capture Legacy & Certificate Expiration Date
            If legacyexpirationdate="" Then
                document.LegacyExpirationDate=legacyexpirationdate  
            End If

            Dim Certificatedat As String
            CertificateDat=ComObj.CertificateData

            'expirationdate=ComObj.ExpirationDate
            expirationdate=COMObj.GetCertExpirationDate(rawdata)

            Dim CertDate As String
            CertDate=ComObj.ExpirationDate

            Dim Debug As String
            Debug=ComObj.xx

            Print "Com expiration:" +CStr(ComObj.ExpirationDate)
            If CStr(expirationdate)<>"" Then
                'Success - Processing Expiration date
                document.ExpirationDate=CStr(expirationdate)
                COMSuccessCount=COMSuccessCount+1
            Else
                'Failed - Processing Expiration date
                document.ExpirationDate=CStr(expirationdate)
                document.COMError="COM Expiration Failed"
                COMErrorCount=COMErrorCount+1
            End If
            Call document.Save(True,False)
        End If

        Set document=view.getnextdocument(document)
    Loop

    'Log Report
    Print "ETH - GetExpirationDLL: Processed "+CStr(TotalCount)+" certificates."
    Print "ETH - GetExpirationDLL: "+CStr(MissingDataCount)+" certificates had missing CSR data."
    Print "ETH - GetExpirationDLL: "+CStr(COMErrorCount)+" certificates failed in the COM Object."
    Print "ETH - GetExpirationDLL: "+CStr(COMSuccessCount)+" certificates were succesfully processed."
    Print "ETH - GetExpirationDLL: End Processing"

    'Delete COMObj

End Sub
```

The two main lines of code above are:

Set COMObj=CreateObject("CertificationInfo.CertificateInformation")

which creates the COM object. The other is:

expirationdate=expirationdate=COMObj.GetCertExpirationDate(rawdata)

which uses the method to pull the expiration date.  As you might have expected, it works fine, however this is where my problem occurs. When I first ran the code it flew, it took roughly 10 minutes to go through 4,000+ records.  I had a few anomalies that I wanted to check, so I ran it a couple more times.  Each time it degraded, and enventually started crawling.  My first thought was it was a memory leak.  Since I was running it locally, I decided to turn off the power to the pc see if it cleared.  It did not.  I also installed it on my laptop to prove to myself it ran smotthly on it's first run. Ran fine on the first one, then perfomance started degrading on consecutive runs.  Last day it was running so slow it was over 8+ hours. This is local machine testing so there are is no servers to contend with network traffic. I am at a complete loss, can anyone tell me what is going on?  CPU is at 20% when running, and Mem usage for notes2.exe growsa little each time.  It slows down when it enters:

expirationdate=expirationdate=COMObj.GetCertExpirationDate(rawdata)

That's the bottleneck. I am completely stuck, does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried writing the whole thing in C#, using the Domino Interop classes?  This is a bit problematic on a 64-bit OS, because IBM does not support the Notes COM classes on 64-bit, and the COM classes are behind the Interop layer. It mostly does work after you get past some registration issues, and I don't see you doing anything in your code that would hit any of the known problems. But if you want to try it as an experiment, it would be interesting to see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Also, I have limited .NET experience so I don't know enough about what might be going on in your ReleaseMemory method, but WaitForPendingFinalizers() raises my suspicions just due to the words "Wait" and "For". Have you tested to see if that's where the real slowdown is? Could there be more and more pending finalizers each time you run, because something that needs to be cleaned up hasn't really been cleaned up?

Comment: First off the Memory Manager method was added after I ran into the performance issue.  I thought it might be a memory leak so I added it to the code before posting this issue. So the memory manager method is not the cause. As to writing it using the interop classes, it has crossed my mind.  I figure it is possible to writie it as a console app, and have a notes agent fire it off through a shell command.  That way the class does all the heavy lifting, but you lose reusability.  So if I wanted to use the method elsewhere I lose that capability. My thought is something is being cached,anyone else

Comment: It does sound like the LotusScript language and/or AMGR is not releasing something. A call to IBM support might be in order for that, I'm afraid. If you're set on having it start in an agent, the console program is one way.  Calling a web service residing on an Windows box might be another, and it wouldn't tie you to the Domino platform specifics, but it's more moving parts and you'd have to have some place to run that web service.

Comment: I'm leaning towards a console app.  May still use the dll for single user action via a button.  7 seconds for a call is acceptable in that case.  I agree, I am going to try one more thing, then going to send this to IBM.  Could be an issue with the Marshaling, or just interop overhead with the looping.  I'll let you know what we find out for others who may run into this.

Comment: So after many days of searching on the internet, with no luck, I solved my problem. Not sure why this works, which I'll have to look into later. When I designed my class I created two ways to pass in values. The magic line = ComObj.CertificateData=rawdata.  Instead of passing it in via the method, I pass it in to the property of the class. 2 minutes later I have ran through all the records succesfully. So why does passing it in through property reference work faster?  In any case the DLL is successful. I'll update my lotus script above with the magic code. Any idea why it works this way?

Comment: I never would have guessed that. Very interesting.  BTW, just for the record, it appears you updated your source code in the question. It would be more in keeping with the spirit of StackOverflow if you would restore it to the way it was, and enter your solution as an answer down below.  That way both the problem and solution are easily visible to others.

Comment: You're passing the string into a field, not a property, at least according to your code. That *might* be a difference from passing it using a method (properties are just syntactic sugar for GetX and SetX methods). And yeah, your "memory manager" is doing more bad than good. Rather than LotusScript not releasing something, I would be affraid it might actually be releasing too eagerly - killing the process space or something. You could try calling `CertificateObject.Reset()` as you clean up, that should be able to safely dispose of the certificate handles.

Comment: Sorry guys I was over ethusiastic, but it was running fast, because it was still reading the old dll, and was passing "" into the method. Uggghhh! So I'm back to were I was at the beginning. I have tried the reset with same results. So I don't beleive the interop is killing me, otherwise it would be super slow when passing it nothing, right? It truly has me baffled. I'll continue to play with and I'll return my code back to the way it was in the beggining. Thought maybe I had something. Could it be passing a string in, not sure what the overhead is on that?

Comment: I'll remove the memory manager as well.

Comment: So I have added some logging to my class and to create the X509Certificate object it tkes 4 seconds on average.  I did a sample of 10 documents. Looks like the overhead for the X509Object is causing the isuue. All other code is minor within a second.  Any idea how to fix the overhead?  Still not sure why it ran so fas the first time it ever ran.  Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas I have feeling it is a memory leak in the X509Certificate object.  Ho would I ensure that it disposes it properly.  What would my finally block need to look like, or do I have to use CRYPT32DLL somehow.  Not sure what to do, can anyo9ne help me or point me in the right direction?